# Customizer: get_preview_url() inside customize_save_after hook

Tags: theme-development, customization, themes, theme-customizer

I am trying to get the `get_preview_url()` inside the `customize_save_after` and save it in an option, but it doesn't work. Is there anyway to get it in this action?

Example code:

```
function funcName( $manager ) {
    $preview_url = $manager->get_preview_url();
    update_option( 'option_name', $preview_url );
}
add_action( 'customize_save_after', 'funcName' );
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why? What is the use case?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it via JS, it does exactly the same thing at the time I want it to:

```
wp.customize.bind( 'saved', function( d ){
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            action: 'actionName',
            url: wp.customize.previewer.previewUrl()
        }
    });
});
```

I can then use the preview URL in an ajax action function.

Don't forget to add a nonce to the above code.

Comment: If anyone has a different solution, please share